# How to require native node module from electron? Getting error with ref and ffi module

Tags: electron, node-ffi

when i require "ref" module in my js code and run via node, I get the desired output.
But when i run the same js code via electron by providing necessary changes in package.json, it says "Could not locate the binding file.."

Here is my package.json file

```
{
"name": "firstapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron .",
    "package": "electron-packager . myapp --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --version=1.0.0 --overwrite"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.4.8",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.8",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.4.0",
    "ffi": "^2.2.0",
    "node-gyp": "^3.4.0",
    "reach": "^1.0.0",
    "ref": "^1.3.3"
},
"dependencies": {
    "ffi": "^2.2.0",
    "ref": "^1.3.3"
}
}
```

And here is my index.js file

```
const electron = require('electron');
const ref = require('ref');
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
let mainWindow
const createWindow = () => {
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ name: "ishwar", width: 800, height: 600, visible: true, toolbar: false });
mainWindow.loadURL(__dirname + '/index.html');

mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null
})
}
app.on('ready', createWindow)
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
app.quit()
})
app.on('activate', () => {
if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
}
})
```

When i start the project "npm start" without requiring "ref" I get no error. But when i do with ref, it throws error.

P.S. The main requirement is for "ffi" module, and I have done necessary changes  needed to run "ffi". "ffi" intern requires "ref", such that when i run code which includes ref via node, it works perfectly..

Comment: Somehow i managed to find the solution. Once i installed the package using normal npm command, i needed to run "electron-rebuild" command for that new package externally. Made change in package.json file and inside script added "rebuildref": "electron-rebuild -f -w ref", "rebuildffi":"electron-rebuild -f -w ffi"  and finally these commands, node run rebuildref and node run rebuildffi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow i managed to find the solution for this one. After I installed these package using npm command, I was getting the binding error. As a solution, I needed to run "electron-rebuild" command for that new package externally. Download electron-rebuild module with npm and then run "electorn-rebuild -f -w ffi" and "electron-rebuild -f -w ref". That's all, its working now.